# What is the octet mode in TFTP?

Tags: c, linux, tftp

I keep hearing about "conversion" of data into octet mode, how does it happen?

Is data in "netascii" bydefault? If I make a TFTP server in C, is it necessary for my packet/buffer variables to be exactly 512 bytes? I mean there are a plethora of functions allowing me to use only 512 bytes of the n bytes of any variable, but for the tftp server does the variable size itself matter?

Comment: This link should help with your question. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: why do you modify your question to add spam and remove all the question content?

Comment: the fact that it's your question doesn't mean that you have the right to remove important information and add junks like that

Comment: The question isn't yours, as per the terms you accepted when you signed up for your account here. You'll find a link to the license agreement in the footer of every page.

Comment: Do not vandalise posts please. Together with the answers this is a combined work under the terms of the CC wiki license; altering the question materially is not something we allow.

Answer (score 15):

In octet mode, data is transferred and stored exactly as-is.  In netascii mode, line endings are converted (if needed) on the receiving end to its preferred line-ending (i.e. Newline on Unixes). There is no default as the mode string is always included in the ReadReQuest or WriteReQuest packet.

[edit] Every packet (except the last) sent must contain exactly 512 bytes of data. If a packet contains less (0..511) it signals the end of the file.
The protocol was designed to able to be implemented with a minimum amount of code, so using a fixed-size buffer was anticipated. You could probably come up with a more complicated scheme, but why?

[RFC 1350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350)* defines the protocol.

[more]

The "Sorcerer's Apprentice Syndrome" is protected against by only sending the next block upon timeout or the receipt of the ***first*** acknowledgment for a block (any further acknowledgments are silently ignored).

The RFC (see section 7) requires an ERROR packet upon error (including malformed request).

**RFC = "Request for Comments". RFC 1350 is the latest and official description and standard for the TFTP protocol.*

Comment: No, if you have sent DATA[n] then you must have previously received ACK[n-1], therefore any further ACK[n-1] is ignored (any ACK[m], where m<n is ignored).  It is a general principle to "be conservative in what you send and liberal in what you accept", however this particular protocol is designed to be simple and small to implement -- in fact, the RFC says "Most errors cause termination of the connection" -- so adding a bunch error recovery code is probably counterproductive.

Comment: No, you resend each time the previous DATA send times out without  an ACK.  All you need to do to prevent S.A.S. is ignore ACKs for previously ACKed DATA's.